# Using a UIScrollview to zoom/pan an image, place items on top of image and move them

Tags: objective-c

I am using a uiscrollview to display an UIImageview that is larger then screen size (just like photo viewing in the Photo Library). next i needed to add a point (i am using a UIImageview to show a dot) to the screen when the user taps. got that working.

now what i am trying to do is have that point to stay in the same location relative to the image. UIScrollview has some notifications for when dragging starts and ends, but nothing that gives a constant update of its contentoffset. say i place a dot at X location. i then scroll down 50 pixels, the point needs to move up 50 pixels smoothly (so the point always stays at the same location relative to the image).

does anybody have any ideas?

EDIT: adding code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //other code...
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = (scrollView.frame.size.width  / imageView.frame.size.width);
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0;    
    //other code...
}
```

adding a point

```
-(void) foundTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    CGPoint pixelPos = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

    UIImageView *testPoint = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"inner-circle.png"]];
    testPoint.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
    testPoint.center = CGPointMake(pixelPos.x, pixelPos.y);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:testPoint];

    NSMutableArray *tempTestPointArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:testPointArray];
    [tempTestPointArray addObject:testPoint];
    testPointArray = tempTestPointArray;

    NSLog(@"recorded point %f,%f",pixelPos.x,pixelPos.y);
}
```

getting pixel points

```
-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"zoom factor: %f", scrollView.zoomScale);
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *test = scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer;

    UIView *piece = test.view;
    CGPoint locationInView = [test locationInView:piece];
    CGPoint locationInSuperview = [test locationInView:piece.superview];

    NSLog(@"locationInView: %@ locationInSuperView: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(locationInView), NSStringFromCGPoint(locationInSuperview));
}
```

Comment: I think you could show the code you are writing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method [`scrollViewDidScroll:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll%3a) to get a continuous callback whenever the content offset changes.

Comment: yep, you are correct! i thought there should be a delegate method that would do this, i must have just missed it, thanks. should be able to solve the problem now with this and adding the point to the correct view.

Comment: The correct approach is the one by Tim, adding the item as a subview of the scrollview, nothing else is needed then.

Comment: you may be correct, the points stay where they should when i pan, but the zoom ability messes up the point locations. when i zoom in, the points zoom to (0, 0) instead of where i pinch to zoom. any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Can you not simply add the image view with the dot as a subview of the scroll view?

Comment: ah, yes. k, i was adding the point (uiimageview) to the view. i changed to add to the main imageview and the scrollview and they will move when scroll/pan'ed, just are not moving in relation to the image now. if i add the point to the scrollview, fully zoomed out they appear where they are placed. but when i zoom in, they move to the upper left (towards the orgin, not to my zoom in location).

Comment: solved the problem. i needed to add the dot as a subview of the main image view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainimg.frame.size);
[mainimg.image drawInRect:
         CGRectMake(0, 0, mainimg.frame.size.width, mainimg.frame.size.height)];

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapButt);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx,2.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
if (largecursor == FALSE) {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, pt.x-3.0, pt.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, pt.x+3.0,pt.y);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, pt.x, pt.y-3.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, pt.x, pt.y+3.0);
} else {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0.0, pt.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, maxx,pt.y);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, pt.x, 0.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, pt.x, maxy);
}

CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
mainimg.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```